# Reading a csv in Julia; CSV.TooManyColumnsError

Tags: pandas, csv, dataframe, julia

In pandas, when we are reading a csv file using the function `pandas.read_csv` we may set the keyword `error_bad_lines = False` which allows us to skip lines with too many fields and guarantee that a DataFrame object is returned. See the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

In Julia I am using `CSV.read` to read some data but no object is returned. Following the [documentation](https://juliadata.github.io/CSV.jl/stable/) I use `CSV.validate` to see what  the problem is  and I get `CSV.TooManyColumnsError`. So I was wondering if there is a similar keyword (to that of pandas) in Julia? More in general, what can be the way to overcome this error and get a DataFrame returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the way CSV.jl should behave by default is to read-in the data and drop the extra columns. Here is an example:

```
julia> using CSV, DataFrames

julia> println(read("x.txt", String))
a,b,c
1,2,3
4,5,6,7,8
1,2
1,2,3


julia> df = CSV.read("x.txt")
4×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ a      │ b      │ c       │
│     │ Int64⍰ │ Int64⍰ │ Int64⍰  │
├─────┼────────┼────────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ 1      │ 2      │ 3       │
│ 2   │ 4      │ 5      │ 6       │
│ 3   │ 1      │ 2      │ missing │
│ 4   │ 1      │ 2      │ 3       │
```

So in short: over-long lines are not skipped, but truncated.
And over-short lines (as you can see in the example) are filled with `missing`. But in all cases you should get the `DataFrame` object returned.

Of course `CSV.validate` should error on the first invalid line:

```
julia> CSV.validate("x.txt")
ERROR: CSV.TooManyColumnsError("row=2, col=3: expected 3 columns then a newline or EOF; parsed row: '4, 5, 6'")
```

Comment: Maybe the OP is using an old version?

Comment: It is possible - that is why I thought it is useful to describe the expected handling of malformed data under current release. This issue has been discussed several months ago and the current behavior is the solution that was decided to be the best most of the time (of course when handling malformed data there is no "single best solution" in general).

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński Is it possible to skip the lines with more columns whereas the file is being read in such a way that the returned dataframe does not contain these lines?

Comment: In your given example it would be not having the second line in the returned df

Comment: As far as I know CSV.jl does not have this option. You can open an Issue to get a feedback from the maintainers if it would be feasible to add this behavior.